# WP7: how to databind to an object member?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a WP7 app that gets data from a DataContext. Say that I have a

```cs
class Country {

    String country_name;
    int population;
    int density;

    ...

}

class City {

    String name;
    Country country;

}
```

I need to have, in databinding, the members of the Country class starting from City class.
If I make `{Binding name}`, I get the city name. How can I get Country properties?  If I try `{Binding country.country_name}`, it does not work.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that doesn't work? It should. Are your classes implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? If not, maybe the value is not set at the moment of the binding and without the notification the binding is never refreshed.

Comment: Actually i return a simple List() of the values...i'll try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, thanks

Comment: If you're using a list use the ObservableCollection class. This will make the items observable. Edit: Sorry, not the items are observable, just the list. You'll have to use INotifyPropertyChanged, too.

Comment: It runs now. Thank you very much!